# Send richtextbox text to batch file

Tags: c#, cmd, richtextbox, multiline

I have a button and a `richtextbox` in my windows form application. I will write something like this:

```
@echo off
echo hi
pause
```

and when I press a button, cmd will run, read the richtextbox and process.

The problem is cmd can't read these multi lines. It closes when I click button. I can understand the problem but how can I solve this?

I found a solution by myself: save the file like `temp.bat` and run it with cmd but is there any other way?

Comment: save the file then use `Process.Start` on it, pretty sure that is the only way (unless there is a 3rd party)

Comment: I think thats the only way to do this.Anyways thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

The first is what you have suggested: make a temp file which holds your commands, then run the file. This is really the easiest and less error-prone.

---

The second way is to use `&` to seperate the commands. You will need to replace all `Enviornment.NewLine` with `&`.

Take this for example (which you can run yourself in command line)

```
echo hey & echo no & echo fish ^& chips & pause
```

You just have to make sure that your input does not have `&`, or you have escape it with a `^`.

[See the documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true) for more.